# Replace Yii2 core class

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

I am looking to override the default Model `\yii\base\Model` class with an extended version I have created. For arguments sake lets say I have it in `backend\components\Model`

I have tried putting both of these in the bootstrap config file but nothing changes - it continues to use the old class

```
Yii::$container->set('yii\base\Model', 'backend\components\Model');
Yii::$classMap['yii\base\Model'] = 'backend\components\Model';
```

and within the backend\Model file:

```
<?php

namespace backend\components;


use Yii;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
use yii\base\UserException;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

class Model extends \yii\base\Model
{
   /**
     * Adds a new error to the specified attribute.
     * @param string $attribute attribute name
     * @param string $key attribute index
     * @param string $error new error message
     */
    public function addCustomError($attribute, $key, $error = '')
    {
        $this->_errors[$attribute][$key][] = $error;
    }
}
```

I have also tried adding it to the config file using:

```
 'container' => [
        'definitions' => [
            'yii\base\model'=>
            ['class'=>'backend\components\model']
        ]
    ],
```

No matter what I do - when I create a new ActiveRecord, it still holds the same yii\base\model class.

I have spent the better half of the afternoon trying to solve this and have gone through both the Yii documentation as well as the questions already on StackOverflow. There seems to be a recurring theme of the Container function not working and people transitioning to the ClassMap function - yet neither seem to work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding by container works if you use container to instantiate overridden class (like `Yii::$container->get('yii\base\Model');`). If you have `class MyModel extends \yii\base\Model` you're NOT using container, `yii\base\Model` will be used as base class no matter what, because this is how PHP works and framework has no way to change that. If you want to do this you have at least 4 options:

1. Preferable: just use `class MyModel extends \backend\components\Model` for your models and avoid hacky class replacing.
2. Desperate 1: copy `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Model.php` to `overridden/Model.php`, alter its source code, and override autoloading config to use `overridden/Model.php` for `yii\base\Model` - add:

   ```
   Yii::$classMap['yii\base\Model'] = __DIR__ . '/../overridden/Model.php';
   ```

   or

   ```
   require __DIR__ . '/../overridden/Model.php';
   ```

   after

   ```
   require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
   require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php
   ```

   **You need to sync all changes from `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Model.php` to your copy after framework update.** In general this should be last resort, since it is really easy to forget about it and get completely unexpected behavior.
3. Desperate 2: patch `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Model.php` directly using [`cweagans/composer-patches`](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches). This is easier to maintain than second option, but it still may be surprising after some time. Also, at some point your patch may get conflicts after framework update and someone that knows what is happening will need to take a look at this.
4. Desperate 3: fork `yiisoft/yii2` and do whatever you want - it is your framework now. It may be quite useful for large and active project, but in other case you may end up with completely outdated framework, because nobody cares to fetch changes from upstream.

Comment: Many thanks @rob006 - the latter options i obviously  don't want to do. Can you give me a concrete example of creating a new active record object (base yii) that instead of using the core Model uses my custom model (which extends base model) using option 1?

Comment: You need create base `backend\components\ActiveRecord` in the same way as you did it for `backend\components\Model` and use it as a base for your AR models (`class MyActiveRecord extends \backend\components\ActiveRecord`). So if you need this both for simple models and active record, you need to create two classes (`backend\components\ActiveRecord` and `backend\components\Model`) and copy `addCustomError()` implementation to both of them.

Comment: The problem I have with that is I am not sure how I can both extend it with my own class and include the Yii2 core class. ie ```ActiveRecord -> BaseActiveRecord-> Model```. I could create 
```MyActiveRecord extends MyBaseActiveRecord -> MyBaseActiveRecord extends MyModel -> MyModel extends Model```, but in doing so I lose all the functionality of the core Yii2 classes in ActiveRecord and BaseActiveRecord (unless I copy and past things over - which we agree is a bad idea) - am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Your `MyBaseActiveRecord` should extend `yii\db\ActiveRecord`.

Comment: Right but $this->_errors is a private variable under the model class - so can't be touched from the ActiveRecord class. So as far as I understand it, I need to add my function to my own Model class, I can't simply add the function to my own ActiveRecord class, I don't believe?

Comment: If it is private, you can't access it in your custom model too - private properties are accessible only in class that declared them. I would suggest to not use `$_errors` private property and define your own property for whatever you want to achieve.